# Draw a shape in QuartzView with the press of a button in the iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, button, uiviewcontroller, drawing, quartz-2d

I want to draw a simple shape in the iPhone simulator when a button is pressed. I can draw it on the screen using the QuartzView without generating an event for the button. However, I want to draw a shape with the touch of a button when an event is generated. I tried to write an IBAction method for the button in both QuartzView and UIViewController. However, I cannot generate an event. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write the following code inside the viewcontroller file. It will work:-

```
-(IBAction) getLine:(id) sender{
    CGPoint currentPoint;
    currentPoint.x=45;
    currentPoint.y=458;
    lastPoint.x=445;
    lastPoint.y=534;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawImage.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.drawImage.frame.size.width, self.drawImage.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.5, 0.6, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

Feel free to ask anything more.

Comment: drawImage method is giving me an error all three times I used it in the ViewController. How did you write drawImage method? The error was "property drawImage was not found in ViewController".

Comment: drawimage is not a method. it is an UIImageView instance. 
so create a UIImageView instance in .h file....  

IBOutlet UIImageView *drawImage;
Drop the UIImageView from object library to the view.
Do the mapping between the UIImageView and drawImage



I have created such a type of application so it will work definitely.
Just try once more. Tell if any problem came.

Comment: To be more precise, drawImage, as is, is a property pointing to a UIImageView. In case you don't want to bother creating a property, just remove the "self." and you will be just ok. I also added a declaration for CGPoint lastPoint; in the end, this quick code example was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your IBAction for the button is like so:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

}
```

with a corresponding

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

in your header. It should then appear as an outlet in Interface Builder.

Comment: I did that in both viewcontroller and quartzview; it did not work.

Comment: Have you correctly set File's Owner to be your custom class instead of a generic one in IB?

Comment: Yes, I did. IBAction is connected with the button. The problem is QuartzView and ViewController cannot communicate.

Comment: Is quartzview a subview of the view contoller? Is it added in IB or programatically?